# Shortcode not working inside div html

Tags: shortcode, html

header.php

```
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v10.0&appId=MyAppIDHere&autoLogAppEvents=1" nonce="mZmuaaHP"></script>
```

Shortcode: functions.php

```
 
function print_onview_meta($atts) {
 
    global $post;
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
 
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('key' => ''), $atts));
 
    if($key && array_key_exists($key, $meta)) {
 
        return $meta[$key][0];
 
    }
    
}
```

Custom Field: wilcity_custom_new_facebook_feed

Output:

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/[onview_meta key='wilcity_custom_new_facebook_feed']" data-tabs="timeline, events, messages" data-width="500" data-height="" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"></div>
```

The result on page is blank, but when I have a look at the dev console it displays the exact code as in the output config above, including the shortcode etc.

What is going wrong here? Any help would be highly appreciated.
(A friend told me I can configure the entire output in the shortcode with echo, but I have no idea how to do this)

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to put a shortcode inside a HTML attribute, it would be easier to build a FB Feed shortcode that printed the entire output. Also, your shortcode function does not return anything if the key does not exist, which is bad. You should add `return '';` to the end of your function

Comment: We found the problem, it was a plugin conflict and everything works fine now. As for not returning anything, this is what should be happening, once nothing is returned the entire field is not displayed on the front end.

Comment: I mean it always needs to return a string, even if it's an empty string. It's not that you return no content, it's that you don't return anything ever. `return '';` is what's needed or you'll generate PHP warnings and notices